# Reseting a useRef array in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

A React Native application contains the following component:

```
export default function MyApp({ route, navigation }) {

   const [pageId, setPageId] = useState(1);
   const childRef = useRef(new Array());

   useEffect(() => {
      // here the requirement is to reset/clear childRef
   }, [pageId]);

     return (
            <View>
              {myArray.map((x, index) => (
                <ChildComponent
                  ref={(element) => childRef.current.push(element)}
                />
              ))}
            </View>
     )
}
```

The above enables a reference to each `ChildComponent` instance to be held in the parent `MyApp`. This allows the parent to call functions on the children. There are other elements which are used to make this work, including `useImperativeHandle` and `forwardRef`, but these details are not relevant for the question.

Buttons exists on `MyApp` which increment and decrement the `pageId` state. This updates the array, and the new child components which represent the updated array are redrawn to the screen.

The issue is that the `childRef` array which holds references to the child components is not being re-initialized when the state of `MyApp` changes and is re-rendered. The result is that functions called using `childRef` are not on the correct `ChildComponent` instances.

The way I am calling a function on a child is as follows:

```
childRef.current[2].nameOfFunction()
```

I would expect this to call the third instance of `ChildComponent` which is displayed.

I have tried various things within `useEffect` to clear the array so that it represents the correct state of the components currently displayed, including:

```
childRef.current.length = 0

childRef.current = [];

childRef.current = new Array();
```

but none of these work correctly.

It does not help to replace `useEffect` with `useLayoutEffect`.
Have also tried to reset the `childRef` array in the decrement/increment buttons prior to incrementing the `pageId` state, but that also does not work.

What is the correct way to reset the `useRef` array, and when/where?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While I still do not a solution to the original question as to how to clear the `useRef` array, I was able to get my program to work correctly by replacing

```
ref={(element) => childRef.current.push(element)}
```

with

```
ref={(element) => (childRef.current[index] = element)}
```

This will update the array elements, but it does require a check that no elements beyond the length of the current `myArray` are accessed.